# ASP.NET web application freeze and not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, clr, windbg

We have a ASP.NET application (.NET Framework 4.5) running on an internal server with IIS Server. Recently we found it becomes freeze a while after restart.

We dumped the memory and analyzed with WinDbg. I found that it stucks on ExecutionManager::FindCodeRangeWithLock. Since .NET Framework 4.5 is not open-sourced, I looked up this C++ method [from github dotnet/runtime repo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/598a7fd1f9be674dd87dae6df25360ea9df3b1e5/src/coreclr/vm/codeman.cpp#L4179), which is using `ReaderLockHolder` to hold the lock in its [ReaderLockHolder Constructor](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/598a7fd1f9be674dd87dae6df25360ea9df3b1e5/src/coreclr/vm/codeman.cpp#L669)

```
    EE_LOCK_TAKEN(GetPtrForLockContract());
```

And I checked the definition of `EE_LOCK_TAKEN` [here on github as well](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d8afd37cc0acc2f23676bdab50ddf3a92f4b04fb/src/coreclr/inc/contract.h#L2069) it takes an enum value `kDbgStateLockType_EE`, which according to the comments

```
    // EE locks (used to sync EE structures).  These do not include
    // CRST_HOST_BREAKABLE Crsts, and are thus not held while managed
    // code runs
    kDbgStateLockType_EE,
```

**cannot be held**

Here is the screenshot from WinDbg and this thread has been running for over 40 minutes. And note that the last frame here is a rethrow since there is a `throw;` in `catch` block from the C# library

[image]

so my question is:

1. Will my analyze based on .NET Core applicable to .NET Framework 4.5? If my guess is correct, why in general there is no blocking when we throw an exception in `catch` block
2. Why does `EECodeInfo::Init` calls `FindCodeRangeWithLock`, since from the github repo, `Init` calls `FindCodeRange`

Edit:

Here is the screenshot of the thread stack running for over 40 minutes by using sosex command `!mk`

In frame 19, managed code threw a `Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.RecoveryTokenException`
and was catched and threw again in frame 0b

[image]

Comment: 1. .NET Core is not .NET Framework, so in most cases you cannot assume anything there. 2. Why analyzing unmanaged call stack when you work on an ASP.NET process dump? Load SOS.dll and analyze managed call stack with `!CLRStack`. You can also use Debug Diag to analyze the dump as it can automatically analyze typical hang/crash cases. Most people should open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and ask Microsoft support team to analyze the dumps, as learning how to find the causes by themselves is unrealistic.

Comment: I did analyze with ```!CLRStack``` from sos and ```!mk``` from sosex, and ```throw;``` in the ```catch``` block triggers frame 0a ```clr!IL_Rethrow+0x98```

Comment: I wonder if you are looking at the right thread. You shared no information on its managed call stack, so it is not sure whether this is one of the worker threads that handles the request and hangs. Did you get a Debug Diag report for this dump? That should reveal many more hints.

Comment: @LexLi I uploaded the screenshot of the thread stack

Comment: So there's some read lock, blocking on a write lock. I assume the write lock happened in another thread. And something has gone wrong somewhere. I doubt we'd be able to help you work out why though.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thx for your comment, so it verified my guess that ```FindCodeRangeWithLock``` was trying to hold a reader lock, for which the corresponding writer lock had been held by another thread

Comment: The managed call stack at least shows some potential causes. You are still working on a legacy project that uses AJAX related code, and the threads seem to be stuck in JavaScript parsing (`JSParser`). That piece of code has been out of maintenance for years, so it's not even easy to locate the right source code and symbol to debug further.

Comment: I would open a support case with Microsoft as this seems to be a bug. This looks a lot like a similar issue that happened to .NET core and was fixed last month, related to stack walking assumptions in AMD64: "The main issue here is a disconnect between what the JIT produces, and the assumption we had around it in the EH code.". The .netcore bug is here:  https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/34526